# Two Versions of the Same OS X App in One Unified Installer

Tags: macos, installation, package

We have two versions of the same OS X application. One version is compiled for OS X 10.7 and will not work on other versions of OS X. The other version of our application is compiled for OS X 10.4 to 10.6 and will not work on OS X 10.7.

We currently ship two installers, however, we'd like to have one unified installer that identifies the target OS and installs the appropriate bundle.

Identifying the OS is easy, it's the choosing of the correct version of the application to install that is not.

We're using Iceberg, and I've investigated using Packages and Vise-X but can't figure out a way to do accomplish the goal. (I think there is a hacky way or tricking Vise-X to do it... if it works I'll update this question.)

Here is how we would like the installer to work

- user executes installer
- installer identifies the version of OS X
- if the target is OS X 10.4 to 10.6 install version 1 of the application
- else if the target is OS X 10.7 choose version 2 of the application

Is there a way of doing this with Iceberg or Packages? Can you point me at an appropriate tutorial or give me the hint that I'm missing?

Alternatively, can you recommend an existing installer tool that does this?

Thank You.